# PHPExcel_Shared_String::SanitizeUTF8 not working in yii when string is special chars like éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç

Tags: yii, special-characters, phpexcel

I got a problem when saving special characters to an excel file using PHPExcel with yii framework. I run the sample 01simple.php and it works fine saving a .xlsx file. But when i checked every cell, A5 value is "FALSE" instead of éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç. I tried to make a fix(make code changes) for several hours in 01simple.php but cant make it. Then found out that when I echoed the value of A5 ( getActiveSheet()->getCell('A5')->getValue();?> ), it's an empty string or maybe space. Tried removing @ sign in @iconv  inside function PHPExcel_Shared_String::SanitizeUTF8 and got an error -> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string. How can i fix this one? really need help.

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
    ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
    ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
    ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
    ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A5')->getValue();//no value
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A4')->getValue();
die;
...
```

Comment: You need to ensure that every string you set in a cell is UTF-8: that error is telling you that there is a character in that string which isn't UTF-8.

Comment: But this is a working code when not using yii. The problem is that why it gets an error inside a yii framework?

Comment: I don't know: I know that the problem isn't in PHPExcel, but I don't know what charset you might be using in yii. I do know that PHPExcel expects UTF-8 for all string values

Comment: Yes, I believe it's in the yii framework. Maybe I'll address this problem to yii. And thanks for the reply.

Comment: I found a solution. Too simple which i disregarded and unnoticed. It's the encoding of my file. It's ANSI. After i changed the encoding to "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM", problem solved. hoooh. Big relief. :)